# Поиск связанных областей в двумерном массиве

Tags: javascript, java, массивы, матрицы

Помогите решить такую проблему. Есть двумерный массив, нужно найти в нем связанные области(тоисть найти всех соседей, что находятся сверху, снизу, слева и справа к данному элементу и к друг другу)  при заданной начальной точке. Например есть такой массив:

```
arr = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,1]
      [2,1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1]
      [3,3,1,3,3,2,2,3,3,2]
      [2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
      [1,1,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,3]
      [1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2]
```

и входная точка пускай будет arr[3][4];
Как мне заменить все 2 на 0 в связанных областях, что бы вышло так:

```
[1,1,0,0,0,3,3,2,3,1]
[2,1,1,0,0,0,3,1,1,1]
[3,3,1,3,3,0,0,3,3,0]
[2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[1,1,1,0,3,3,0,0,3,3]
[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

Желательно код на js или java.

Comment: Задача не поставлена. Почему 2 на 0 заменяется, а 1 не трогали?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=L-ZfW5XqD4S4swGqwJyADw&q=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2&oq=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4880.4880.0.5597.1.1.0.0.0.0.112.112.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.2OkTLYAp1AM ???

Comment: по какому принципу не все двойки заменились на нули?

Comment: Заменяются лишь те элементы, которые являются соседями, тоесть есть сверху, снизу, слева или справа. Цифры поставлены к примеру... Нужен просто алгоритм поиска в матрице соседних элементов для выбранного элемента. Не могу даже толковый алгоритм придумать...

Comment: А вы даже и не думали, ибо тут просто берете нужные индексы (+-1) и все

Comment: Вы можете проверить четыре элемента вокруг данного? А потом вокруг тех из них, в которых то же число? А потом опять?

Comment: А как избежать повторных проверок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А, ну теперь понятно, это довольно простая рекурсивная задачка:

```js
//Объявляем массив с кучей массивов
let arr=[
 [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,1],
 [2,1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1],
 [3,3,1,3,3,2,2,3,3,2],
 [2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
 [1,1,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,3],
 [1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2]
]
function fn(arr,k,c,replace,needle){
  //проверяем, находимся ли мы всё ещё в границах массива
  if(arr[c]===undefined||arr[c][k]===undefined) return
  //узнаём значение по переданным координатам
 let numb=arr[c][k]
 //если needle не передан, значит это первый запуск
 if(needle===undefined) needle=numb
 //если выбранный элемент совпадает, то изменяем число и создаём новые четыре ветки рекурсии, по одной на каждую сторону
 if(numb===needle){
  arr[c][k]=replace
  let ks=[k-1,k+1,k,k],
  cs=[c,c,c+1,c-1]
  ks.forEach((v,k)=>fn(arr,v,cs[k],replace,needle))
 }
}
fn(arr,3,4,0)
arr.forEach(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)));
```

Тоже самое на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcmagvjL/4/)